# Can javascript be used to render web pages

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In my project i am using jsp for templating and java as backend. This was the first time I was using jsp and javascipt i have few questions about it.

I learnt that we can dynamically render a page using javascript so does that makes the jsp redundant?

If "js" can be used for rendering pages then what are the advantages of using jsp?

Comment: can somebody please add the reason for downvote? that would be more constructive

Comment: JS works on the client side and JSP on the server side. You should separate those two concepts before doing any form of web development

Comment: i know the difference between jsp and js , but my question was more focused on if we can use js for rendering pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Server Pages (JSP) were a templating solution invented as a response to Microsoft's ASP.  It gave developers a way to create dynamic web pages that would respond to data from the server side.

JSP is a template language that is parsed and compiled into a Java servlet, which is subsequently compiled from .java to a .class file.  The servlet/JSP engine on the server side uses it to generate HTML dynamically and stream it to the browser.

There are lots of other templating solutions out there (e.g. Velocity).

It's entirely possible to use JavaScript to dynamically manipulate the DOM - that's what jQuery is all about.

JSP only works if you're a Java developer committed to the Java EE stack.

If you're a web developer expecting to deal with REST services, I think it's less likely that you'd choose JSP.

"redundant" is too strong a negative term, IMO.  Think of JSP as one choice among many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use JavaScript to render the page. You just need to return the required data from the server.

JSP is still needed in many cases. For example, you want to return different content for different user depending on the user's group (e.g., manager, employee). You can write a JSP that retrieves user's group, and then return the right content. To do this using JavaScript, you need to return all possible content. Your JavaScript then retrieves the user's group, and then show the right content.

Answer (score 0):

Those are different architecture, each having its benefits and downsides

Jsp templating is made on the server side, while JS runs on the client's browser : that can make your server serve more client as it has less work to do, and less data to send

Jsp will use the same DAOs as your backend, JS will need a rewriting of some of it

That's just the two first that comes to my mind and there's a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is client side language and jsp is server side language, If you need client side tempting/ or load partials(spa) then you can use javascript, while if you are using application like shopping cart then you should use jsp/php ....